# Unable to locate Package Synaptic

Tags: apt, software-installation, synaptic

I am beginning to explore Ubuntu as a new user.  I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS from a flash drive. In attempting to install software that was not already bundled in the Ubuntu download I read on this forum that I should use the command line of the terminal to install the Synaptic package manager.
I entered the command

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

but I get the following responses:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Synaptic
```

What do I need to do to be able to install widely used open source software apps that are not the defaults in this download of Ubuntu?

Comment: Synaptic is universe, so try enabling universe.

Comment: You have the correct install command, but you first have to do a `sudo apt-get update` to update the software database.

Answer (score 0):

Linux is almost always **case sensitive** meaning that `Synaptic` and `synaptic` are not the same.

Also please note that any packages you install after selecting "Try Ubuntu" from the USB thumb drive are not going to stay once you power the system off. You can either install Ubuntu or prepare a [persistent USB thumb drive](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent) that will save data once the system is turned off.